# How can I position list in <div>?

Tags: html, css

I have a  `<div>` and it has a image in background.
Now I want to put a list into that Div so how can I position that in

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWmB2.png

you can See in above picture I have background and a list but I am not able to position it.

My Code

```
<div id="footer">
        <div id="footer-content">
            <div id="footer-list">
                <ul>

                    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#news">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">About FF</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">FAQ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">How To Play</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">Terms of Use</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">Privacy Policy</a></li>

                </ul>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

css--

```
#footer-list ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 500px;
    margin-top:  100px;
}
#footer
{
    background-image: url(/img/footer.png);
    height: 140px; 
    width: 1820px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    left:0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

The problem with my css is when I am giving the 'margin-top:100px' to ul it goes down but the background pic is also goes down.

So how can I position the list in div?

Comment: <ul> tags should be inside #footer-list div to have a valid markup

Comment: actually im giving the style to <li> using that

Comment: Yes, but if you don't use a valid markup you can get weird behaviours from the browser when it tries to render the page even if your css is correct

Comment: stil the same problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you want. When u use `<ul>` u can't use `<div>` inside that. So checkout this

```css
#footer-content ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 500px;
}
#footer-content ul li {
     display: inline;
}
#footer
{
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWmB2.png');
    height: 140px; 
    width: 1820px; 
    background-size: 1820px 140px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    left:0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    padding-top:50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
        <div id="footer-content">
            <ul>
                    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#news">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">About FF</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">FAQ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">How To Play</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">Terms of Use</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">Privacy Policy</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: why it is not working.? what is happend to this? do u need to move the <li> tags to left or right ?

Comment: it is my footer and when I am giving margin-top they both goes down.

Comment: have you seen the image that I have uploaded I want the list below the line in Image so I am just giving the margin-top but it also get the bgImage down too

Comment: to what element did u put the margin-top ?

Comment: I have put it to '<ul>'

Comment: I just need that in image my list should come 50 to 70 pixel down

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76229/discussion-between-harshana-samaranayaka-and-bhavik-joshi).

Answer (score 1):

You also have to change the CSS...

```
#footer-list ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 500px;
    margin-top:  100px;
}
#footer
{
    background-image: url('/img/footer.png');
    height: 140px; 
    width: 1820px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    left:0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
#footer-list{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: are you still getting the same result in browser?

Comment: yes it is my footer and when I am giving margin-top they both goes down